# Angular way to submit the form automatically without click or shown

Tags: angularjs, payment-gateway

Hi I have 2 webforms in which the first form have a submit button and the second form just deals with ajax response using $http service. When the user clicks submit button in the first form, it has to be return  response as second form (only form dom ) where user doesn't require any control over the second form. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the Angular jqLite wrapper m8:

```
angular.element("#form--login").submit()
```

You can then mock/spyOn `angular.element` in your tests.